# Do I have to declare a empty array inside of a object in Javascript before using it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I just started learning Javascript, and one of the problems I did was calculating a tip based on a amount paid. This was my first attempt:

```
var john = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calculateTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] < 200) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.15;
            } else {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
            }
        }
        return this.tips;
    }
};

john.calculateTip();
console.log(john.tips);
```

But this was the error I would get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at Object.calculateTip (script.js:8)
    at script.js:17
calculateTip @ script.js:8
(anonymous) @ script.js:17
```

Then I just declared a empty array inside of a object:

```
var john = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tips: [],
    calculateTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] < 200) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.15;
            } else {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
            }
        }
        return this.tips;
    }
};

john.calculateTip();
console.log(john.tips);
```

And it worked just fine.

### My question is

When I was making a normal variable inside a function inside of a object, and not an array, I didn't have to declare it beforehand. Is this always the case with arrays, and if someone can explain the error I got a bit more?

Comment: Yes because this.tips (without declaration) returns "undefined" which is not a array. And indexing a non array (more generally object in case of javascript) throws error.

Comment: A solution is that before for loop declare this.tips = []; and then run for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just link to the fact that in any declared JS Object you can refers to any property name (You'll just have an undefined value) :

```
var test = { name: "Hello" }
console.log(test.anything) // Would print undefined

var test2 = { 
             name: "Hello"
             test3 : {}
            }

console.log(test2.test3.anything) // Would print undefined
```

But in your case you're trying to acces a specific index of a tab that doesn't exist so isn't indexed

Your error refers to the first assignement you're trying :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

At this line when `i = 0` :

```
this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
      ^
   undefined
Then undefined[0] would throw the error
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to declare complex objects before accessing them. 
There is simply reason why you should do that - every object field has a value `undefined` if value wasn't set at all.
In this case you just trying to access first element of `undefined` value which is caused the Error.
The same Error will be thrown if you want to access sub-property of property that is `undefined`

```
var a = {
    b: '111'
}

a.c.d = '222'
```

won't work because property `c` is missing and it's value is `undefined`. You should create property `c` first

```
var a = {
    b: '111',
    c: {}

}

a.c.d = '222'
```

will work